# How to get the value inside a div tag in a table using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to do automation for one of my application using selenium webdriver. The problem is I am trying to fetch the data from table which contains the value inside a "div" tag.The table is nothing but a calendar.

This is my code for fetching the value from table.(i.e.,div tag)

```
public boolean webElement_Table_findCellValue_WD(String locatorType, String locatorVal, String cellText){
    boolean elementStatus = false;  
    WebElement tbl = this.getWebElement(locatorType, locatorVal);

    List<WebElement> tbTag=tbl.findElements(By.tagName("table"));

    int num=tbTag.size();
    System.out.println("hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh"+num);

    for(WebElement tbTagEle: tbTag)
    {
        List<WebElement> trTag=tbTagEle.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
        System.out.println("iiiiiiiiiiiiii"+trTag.size());

        for(WebElement trTagEle: trTag)
        {
            List<WebElement> tdTag=trTagEle.findElements(By.tagName("td"));
            System.out.println("jjjjjjjjjjjjj"+tdTag.size());
            for(WebElement tdTagEle: tdTag)
            {
                List<WebElement> divTag=tdTagEle.findElements(By.tagName("div"));
                for(WebElement divTagEle: divTag)
                System.out.println("the contents are:"+divTagEle.getText());
            }
        }
    }

    return elementStatus;   

}
```

My intention is just to select(click) a date from the calender.(Table) which I will pass it through a properties file.

Comment: `findElements(By.cssSelector("table tr td div"))` After, you can get the element(s) text and select the one that you desire to click. I really dunno how to do it in java, i use c# while I develop using Selenium, and I use linq expression to select it.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand this. Could you post your actual HTML so I can try to get my head around this table/div nesting?

Answer (score 0):

In answer to the first part of the question, @Striter Alfa got most of the way.

The following will print the content of each `<div>` within each cell within each table (whether one or multiple):

```
for (WebElement elem : driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("table td div"))) {
    System.out.println("Each div:" + elem.getText());
}
```

I don't know whether you need to store those values in a `List`. The rest of your question isn't very clear, but hopefully you will be able to solve it from here.

Comment: Thnx Striter for your answer.

Comment: Hi Andrew, My requirement is i have to click on a particular date in the calender(which is there in the table format). Here each date is in the separate table tag. like:<table><div><table><tbody><tr><td> <div> Here date value is getting display as 1.

Comment: There is separate <table> for each date,and the date value is inside the <div> tag which i mentioned in the above comment.I just want to click on the particular date in that calender,which i will pass that via properties file.

Answer (score -1):

The following will find the specific date table and click on the same.pass date value as parameter.
`WebElement el = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table//div[contains(.,'"+date+"')]"))
el.click();`